# Results from the table and link

Tags: php, hyperlink

I do not know how to add a link to the results of table.
I want to change `<a href="#">#</a>` to
`<a href="photo_update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">edit</a>`

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

```
foreach($results as $row) {
   $table  = '<tr>';
   $table .= '<td>';
   $table .= $row['filename'];
   $table .= '<a href="#">#</a>';
   $table .= '</td>';
   $table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">';
   $table .= $row['size'];
   $table .= '</td>';
   $table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">';
   $table .= $row['type'];
   $table .= '</td>';
   $table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">&pound;';
   $table .= $row['caption'];
   $table .= '</td>';
   $table .= '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fifth line of your code, instead of

```
$table .= '<a href="#">#</a>';
```

you should write

```
$table .= '<a href="photo_update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">edit</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results as $row) {

$table  = '<tr>';
$table .= '<td>';
$table .= $row['filename'];
$table .= "<a href='photo_update.php?id={$row['id']}'>edit</a>";
$table .= '</td>';
$table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">';
$table .= $row['size'];
$table .= '</td>';
$table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">';
$table .= $row['type'];
$table .= '</td>';
$table .= '<td class="col1 nw tar">&pound;';
$table .= $row['caption'];
$table .= '</td>';
$table .= '</tr>';

}
```